# Sum cells in range while contains a specific name

Tags: excel

I have an excel with each row looks something like this :

```
Project Name, Rate, Person1, Person2, Person3
```

An example with several rows :

```
My Project, 1000, John, Jack, Jim
Project 2,  2000, Jack, Jim
```

In another table, I have a list of all persons and I would like each person's name will include the sum of all of his earning. The output for the example I provided sound be:

John: 1000 (John only worked in "My project"
Jack: 3000 (Jack worked in both projects therefore 1000 + 2000)
Jim: 3000 (Jim worked in both projects therefore 1000 + 2000)

I am trying to have the sum automatically populated for each person based on the spreadsheet provided.

I tried using IFSUM however my problem is that when a name exists in the list it should add the amount in "rate" always and I couldn't figure a way of doing that.

Comment: do you try VBA?

Comment: another approach could be through a pivot table, you can summarise the data, i.e. person, project, rate. Here is a a how to: https://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html

Comment: Show us what you have tried?  You can use formulas, VBA, Power Query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I not sure if your data is in single cell or cell by cell in each row. Try `SUMPRODUCT()` if your data looks like below.

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$1:$B$2*($C$1:$E$2=G1))
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!